# git config credential.helper not working on linux with version 2.11.0

Tags: git, git-config

I can not understand why the "git config credential.helper" (store or cache) command is not working.

I am on linux and git version is the "2.11.0".
First I did:

```
git init
git remote add -f origin username@git.mywebsite.com:projects/myproject
git config core.sparseCheckout true
echo "path/to/my/dir/" > .git/info/sparse-checkout
git checkout
```

After that I tried:

```
git config credential.helper store
git pull
```

After that, the system asks me for password.
I enter the password, but nothing is saved.
If I do "git pull" again, system asks me for password again.

I tried with:
    `git config credential.helper cache`

either with same results.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: did you solve your issue?

Comment: I solved, but honestly i do not remember how.